# Qt objects not identified by UFT automation tool

Tags: qt, qtp, hp-uft

I have a window based application developed in Qt framework. When I try to automate it using UFT tool, the objects are not recognized. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.learnqtp.com/complete-support-matrix/), UFT offers compatibility with Qt 4.80 on UFT 12.51 and 12.52, and for Qt 4.60, it offers compatibility from UFT 12.01 and later. This might be the reason why you are unable to identify the objects. I can't offer much more assistance to that, since I've never worked with Qt applications. Best of luck

Comment: [This article](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/hp-uft/hp-uft-unified-functional-testing-tool-features/) also says something about offering support to Qt (see item 8). You need to have the Qt add-in installed in order to make it work....this is as far as I can go